# mongodb: field sorted by number of occurances

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with each document representing a virtual auction. I want to find the most common item ID for a given time period. In SQL, I'd `SELECT item, COUNT(*) as count` with `GROUP BY item` and the usual sorting and limits. Is there a mongodb equivalent to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB has several options here.

- In version 2.1.0+ you can use the new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/). There's a conversion chart right [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Aggregation+Framework+Mapping+Chart).
- In older versions you can use either a [Map / Reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce)
- For simple versions of aggregation you ca use the special [aggregation operators](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group).

Each of these options will have a different syntax and a different speed.

In any of these cases, you will likely find these options relatively slow. Map / Reduce jobs are intended to be run "off-line", generally as a "cron job" or "scheduled task". Note that if you plan to do this a lot, you will likely want to pre-aggregate this data.

Comment: I now have a Map / Reduce operation that runs once an hour into a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) and then sort the output collection or you can use the command [group](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation), but you will need to do most of the sorting and limit on the client side.

Example for group command:

```
db.coll.group(
       {key: { a:true, b:true },
        cond: { active:1 },
        reduce: function(obj,prev) { prev.csum += obj.c; },
        initial: { csum: 0 }
        });
```

It's also worth to mention that in the next stable version of mongodb (2.2) they will release a new [aggregation framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework), which will make this operations much easier.